# Stabilizing Neural Network

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to build a neural network and have the following code:

```
for i = 1:num_samples-num_reserved

        % Getting the sample and transposing it so it can be multiplied
        sample = new_data_a(:,i)';

        % Normalizing the input vector
        sample = sample/norm(sample);

        % Calculating output
        outputs = sample*connections;

        % Neuron that fired the hardest's index (I) and its output (output)
        [output, I] = max(outputs);

        % Conections leading to this neuron
        neuron_connections = connections(:,I);

        % Looping through input components
        for j = 1:num_features

            % Value of this input component
            component_input = sample(j);

            % Updating connection weights
            delta = 0.7*(component_input - neuron_connections(j));

            neuron_connections(j) = neuron_connections(j) + delta;


        end


        % Copying new connection weights into original matrix
        connections(:,I) = neuron_connections/norm(neuron_connections);

        if(rem(i,100) == 0)

            if(I == 1)

                delta_track = [delta_track connections(2,I)];

            end

        end

        % Storing current connections



    end
```

I think I'm doing everything right. This loop is repeated about 600 times so as to progressively update connections. The function to update weights I am using is the standard one I found in textbooks.

However, when I look at the values stored in delta_track These keep oscillating forming  a regular pattern.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the feedback factor. Then the network may require more time to learn but is less likely to oscillate. 
Another common technique is to add a decay, i.e. reducing the factor each iteration.
In general neural networks have the same stability rules as control systems have (because as long as a NN is learning it is a control system) Therefore similar approaches work as for e.g. PID controllers.

Comment: Thanks - I will implement both of these techniques :) Do you think there is anything wrong in my overall approach though?

Comment: I agree that having the learning rate decay is a good approach. This is a pretty standard thing to do. It helps you converge more precisely as you get closer to the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Fookie, settng the feedback factor to 1/n where n is the number of testing 'rounds' worked :)

Comment: Next step usually is to evaluate other learning mechanisms. Now you have a (pretty fast) decay. Some start reducing the factor after the delta for n is higher than n-1. Some do evolutionary learning. There is a lot of fun ahead for you.